# How to extend search record to also look at custom Many2Many field(s)?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

In this image, there is a product search record that will search for `name` and `default_code`. I need to make it so that it will also look at my custom Many2Many field.

[image: Search Product]

This is the field in the inherited model.

```
product_list = fields.Many2many("product.list", string="Product List")
```

The custom model only has _name, _description, and name variables.

The question is how to make the search to also look at all of the possible Many2Many data of this field.

I have tried this in the inherited model:

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    res = super(product_template_inherit, self).name_search(name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100)
    ids = self.search(args + [(name, 'in', 'product_list.name')], limit=limit)
    if ids:
        return ids.name_get()
    return res
```

Nothing happens to the search. It still searches using the same behavior regardless of the code above.

**Summary**: I need to be able to search product by product list (custom Many2Many field inherited in the `product.template` model)

=============================================

**UPDATE**

Current code from what I have been trying is now this.

```
@api.model
def _name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100, name_get_uid=None):
    args = args or []
    if operator == 'ilike' and not (name or '').strip():
        domain = []
    else:
        domain = ['|', ('name', 'ilike', name), ('product_list.name', 'ilike', name)]
        product_ids = self._search(expression.AND([domain, args]), limit=limit, access_rights_uid=name_get_uid)
    return self.browse(product_ids).name_get()
```

However, it looks like it still searches using the same old fields. It does not change to behave as my function is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the search domain then return the result of the `_search` method.

The [fleet](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/fleet/models/fleet_vehicle.py#L276) module already uses the same logic to search vehicles using the driver name, you have just to replace the `driver_id` with `product_list`:

```py
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    @api.model
    def _name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100, name_get_uid=None):
        args = args or []
        if operator == 'ilike' and not (name or '').strip():
            domain = []
        else:
            domain = ['|', ('name', operator, name), ('product_list.name', operator, name)]
        return self._search(expression.AND([domain, args]), limit=limit, access_rights_uid=name_get_uid)
```